# Cross platform podcatcher with a play history

Tags: cross-platform, file-synchronization, collection-manager, podcast, history

I want to sync podcasts with a crappy underwater MP3 player, and intend to script my way there.

I use Pocket Casts on android, and while it does have a "in progress" tracker it doesn't record your finished podcasts. Stitcher doesn't seem helpful either.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you might need [gpodder](http://gpodder.org/):

- Open Source, cross-platform, fast and clean
- Synchronize subscription and playback state between devices
- Linux, FreeBSD, Windows, Mac OS X, the Nokia N9, Blackberry 10, the Blackberry Playbook, Sailfish OS and Android
- gPodder downloads and manages free audio and video content ("podcasts") for you. Listen directly on your computer or on your mobile devices.

[image]

Comment: ty, here's hoping.